# Are there 3D geometric proofs of Fibonacci identities?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers, visualization

There is a significant number of identities involving Fibonacci numbers that can be proven in a sort of geometric way, as it is shown in the following picture:

[image]

However, I couldn't find any such proof that involves 3D geometry. I also couldn't find any Fibonacci identity that would be suitable for such interpretation.

Is there an inherent reason for such proofs being limited to 2D?

Is there a series (different then Fibonacci) that would be suitable for similar 3D geometric proofs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, there is one 3D proof of a Fibonacci identity:

[image]

Comment: Brilliant interception.